# aiohttp.ClientSession does not set cookie with 'expires' key

Tags: python, cookies, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a dummy server that sends a cookie with `Set-Cookie`, that I call with a `aiohttp.ClienSession`.

When I send a simple cookie with a name and a value, the session stores it in its cookie jar.
However, if I add an `expires` key, then the cookie is not stored at all.

This behaviour happens only with the `expires` key, and not the other standard keys.
Also, when I use a `requests.Session` instead, the cookie is correctly stored.

Is there an issue with the way I send the cookie?

---

Here's the code of the server:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/cookie/<name>/<value>")
def send_cookie(name, value):
    cookie = f"{name}={value}"
    response = flask.Response(status=200, headers={"Set-Cookie": cookie})
    return response

@app.route("/cookie/expires/<name>/<value>")
def send_expiring_cookie(name, value):
    cookie = f"{name}={value}; expires=Wed, 15 Jan 2020 09:45:07 -0000"
    response = flask.Response(status=200, headers={"Set-Cookie": cookie})
    return response

app.run("localhost")
```

With the `aiohttp.ClientSession`:

```
import asyncio as aio
import aiohttp

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.get("http://localhost:5000/cookie/hello/world")
        print(session.cookie_jar._cookies)
        # defaultdict(<class 'http.cookies.SimpleCookie'>, {'localhost': <SimpleCookie: hello='world'>})

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.get("http://localhost:5000/cookie/expires/hello/world")
        print(session.cookie_jar._cookies)
        # defaultdict(<class 'http.cookies.SimpleCookie'>, {})

loop = aio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

With `requests.Session`:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get("http://localhost:5000/cookie/hello/world")
    print(session.cookies)
    # <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie hello=world for localhost.local/cookie/hello>]>

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get("http://localhost:5000/cookie/expires/hello/world")
    print(session.cookies)
    # <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie hello=world for localhost.local/cookie/expires/hello>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the cookie is not set is that it is not successfully parsed.
The `aiohttp` module relies upon `http.cookies` from the standard library and its `SimpleCookie` class.

When a response arrives, its headers are inspected for a `Set-Cookie` key, and the value associated to it is used to instanciate `SimpleCookie`.
The latter has a `load` method, which parses the cookie string and extracts the cookie info.
To achieve this, the cookie string is matched against a regex, `_CookiePattern`, defined in the same module at line 434 (on tag `v3.7.2`):

```
_CookiePattern = re.compile(r"""
    \s*                            # Optional whitespace at start of cookie
    (?P<key>                       # Start of group 'key'
    [""" + _LegalKeyChars + r"""]+?   # Any word of at least one letter
    )                              # End of group 'key'
    (                              # Optional group: there may not be a value.
    \s*=\s*                          # Equal Sign
    (?P<val>                         # Start of group 'val'
    "(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"                  # Any doublequoted string
    |                                  # or
    \w{3},\s[\w\d\s-]{9,11}\s[\d:]{8}\sGMT  # Special case for "expires" attr
    |                                  # or
    [""" + _LegalValueChars + r"""]*      # Any word or empty string
    )                                # End of group 'val'
    )?                             # End of optional value group
    \s*                            # Any number of spaces.
    (\s+|;|$)                      # Ending either at space, semicolon, or EOS.
    """, re.ASCII | re.VERBOSE)    # re.ASCII may be removed if safe.
```

From this pattern, we can read that the expected pattern for the `expires` attribute is:

```
\w{3},\s[\w\d\s-]{9,11}\s[\d:]{8}\sGMT
```

This pattern implements (in a somewhat convoluted and not absolutely accurate but still short way) the date format as specified by [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date).

As a result, my cookie whose `expires` field is `expires=Wed, 15 Jan 2020 09:45:07 -0000` is naturally ignored, as the timezone is expressed as `-0000` while it's expected to be `GMT`.
By the way, here's what [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date) say about that:

> GMT
>
> Greenwich Mean Time. HTTP dates are always expressed in GMT, never in local time.

The conclusion is that my cookie is simply malformed.
And unsurprisingly enough, replacing `-0000` by `GMT` works.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, thank you for providing such a great working example of the problem!

I managed to make your solution store the cookie by making escaping the spaces in the expires field, like so:

```
import re

import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/cookie/<name>/<value>")
def send_cookie(name, value):
    cookie = f"{name}={value}"
    response = flask.Response(status=200, headers={"Set-Cookie": cookie})
    return response

@app.route("/cookie/expires/<name>/<value>")
def send_expiring_cookie(name, value):
    exp_date = re.escape("Wed, 15 Jan 2020 09:45:07 -0000")
    cookie = f"{name}={value}; expires={exp_date}"
    response = flask.Response(status=200, headers={"Set-Cookie": cookie})
    return response

app.run("localhost")
```

I think the issue is because of the way aiohttp parses the date. I don't know off hand what they claim should work, but it's definitely using a regular expression to parse the date, so it would make some sense that it needs to be escaped.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer! Yeah it's definitely due to the way the cookie is parsed, but it's even worse: if the key is `Expires` with an uppercase `E`, it works... I'll have a look at that. If I'm not mistaken, `aiohttp` uses cookies from `http.cookies`, my guess is that `requests` uses something different. I'll keep you informed!